# How to break this summation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, linear-regression

I see least square's slope like this
$$a=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)(y_i-\bar y)}{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)^2}$$
But I also see the top part like this
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \sum_{i=1}^n y_i}n$$
 My question is how to break $\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)(y_i-\bar y)$ down to $\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \sum_{i=1}^n y_i}n$
Thanks.

Comment: What are $x$ and $y$?

Comment: I am basically talking about linear regression =+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about your notation. But I think this is the answers you are looking for:

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y}) &=& \sum_{i=1}^n(x_iy_i - x_i\bar{y}-\bar{x}y_i+\bar{x}\bar{y})  \\
&=& \sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i - \bar{y}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i - \bar{x}\sum_{i=1}^ny_i+n\bar{x}\bar{y} \\
&=& \sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i - n\bar{y}\bar{x} - n\bar{x}\bar{y}+n\bar{x}\bar{y}  \\ 
&=& \sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i - n\bar{y}\bar{x} \\ 
&=& \sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i - n\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{n}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^ny_i}{n} \\ 
&=& \sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i \sum_{i=1}^ny_i}{n}
\end{eqnarray}

Then you got it!

Comment: That's right. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome!